# Setting an MVC ASP.NET application to do scheduled tasks - Method to achieve it?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I am building a website that will fetch data from xml feeds. I am building it as an MVC AP.NET application. I will need the application to get data from the xml files located on the provider's server every 2 minutes for example. These data will then be stored.
My problem is that I want these procedure to be done without interruption from the moment the website will be uploaded on server. I was thinking of using a timer in the main method(?) to get the data every 2 minutes. But I have searched other topics here and I found out that using AppFabric would be the solution. The problem is that I am an absolute beginner and I find it difficult to use it... Is there an other more simple way to achieve this continuous update of data from the xml file?

Comment: The data will be stored in the database the ASP.NET website uses? Couldn't you do the fetching in a Console app which would be fired by a timer job? Then you wouldn't need the website to worry about this. Also, I believe AppFabric is used for caching mainly.

Comment: Why do you want to make it a web application when you are not serving web pages and responding to web requests?  You should make this a scheduled task, or write a Windows Service.  IIS will shutdown your website when it is inactive, which means your task won't run.

Comment: The web app will get data from xml feeds, store them in lists/tables and in the future some of them will be stored in databases. I need the data in the lists/tables to be updated and send updates data to the views. Website visitors will just see the Views

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would recommend you use Quartz to handle the scheduling instead of using the built-in timer.  I have used Quartz in my last two projects and I have been very impressed.  It can handle about any schedule you can think of.

http://www.quartz-scheduler.net/documentation/quartz-2.x/quick-start.html

Example Job Creation:

```
using Quartz;
using Quartz.Impl;

IScheduler scheduler = StdSchedulerFactory.GetDefaultScheduler();
scheduler.Start();

IJobDetail integrationJob = JobBuilder.Create<IntegrationJob>().Build();

ITrigger integrationTrigger = TriggerBuilder.Create()
            .StartNow()
            .WithSimpleSchedule(x => x.WithIntervalInSeconds(300).RepeatForever()).Build();

scheduler.ScheduleJob(integrationJob, integrationTrigger);


public class IntegrationJob : Ijob
{
    public void Execute(IJobExecutionContext context)
    {
        //Write code for job
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you! But I am a beginner, I have another question: The scheduled task will pull the xml data and update the lists/tables is the model. Then, Views will be updated due to the updated model data. Will this work regardless if users visit the website or not, right? And if server restarts, it will start again, right?

Comment: You want to make sure you have the .StartNow() extension method when you add the job like I showed above.  Then you want to wrap the scheduling portion of the code in another class or just drop it into your global.asax.cs and as soon as IIS starts up the job will run regardless of any requests being made to the web server.

Answer (score 0):

Another, simpler and more straight forward approach is to create a Console project in your Visual Studio solution and have the Windows Task Scheduler kick it off. To do this you'll need to have at least the three following projects in your solution:

- A Class Library project with your Domain Models and Repository classes
- The ASP.NET MVC web application (which references the Domain Models project)
- The Console project (which references the Domain Models project)

Ideally you would to adhere to Domain Driven Design so your business logic is encapsulated in your Domain Models, and therefore portable between your web application and console app.

Really, I would recommend this solution setup for any project that might be more than just a web app:

- `MyApp.Models`: A Class Library for your domain models and Repository classes. Utilize [Domain Driven Design](http://dddcommunity.org/learning-ddd/what_is_ddd/) and the [Repository Pattern](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff649690.aspx) to make core business logic and access to persistent storage portable between VS projects
- `MyApp.Models.Tests`: Unit tests for your models class library
- `MyApp.Web`: MVC or WebForms project
- `MyApp.Web.Tests`: Unit and functional tests for your web project.

  - Unit Tests: Use your favorite test runner (MS Test, NUnit, xUnit, etc)
  - Functional Tests: [CodedUI tests](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd286726.aspx) from Microsoft or [WatiN](http://watin.org/) allow you to drive the web browser programmatically. I would also recommend [SpecFlow](http://www.specflow.org/) for those who want to do [Behavior Driven Development](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Behavior-driven_development)
- `MyApp.Console`: The console application that can be run as a background job
- `MyApp.Console.Tests`: Unit tests for your console application

I know this seems like overkill, but in my experience projects always seem to gravitate towards this structure over time. Building your project with this structure in mind is easy, and gives you a lot of flexibility as The Business takes the inevitable dive into insanity and requires your application to do everything but make coffee (that's what interns are for, after all!).

Answer (score 0):

You may want to look into using [Hangfire](http://hangfire.io/). It lets you schedule tasks and gives you a nice dashboard to manage tasks. You can find it in NuGet and the documentation on the Hangfire site is pretty good.

It's very easy to use, here's an example of what you have to add to the OWIN Startup class if you want to run a job every minute:

```
public void Configuration(IAppBuilder app)
{
    app.UseHangfire(config =>
    {
        config.UseSqlServerStorage("connection string");
        config.UseServer();
    });

   InitializeJobs();
}

public static void InitializeJobs()
{            
    RecurringJob.AddOrUpdate("jobName", () => CallToJobFunction(), Cron.Minutely);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Checkout hanselman's blog where he discusses this topic:
http://www.hanselman.com/blog/HowToRunBackgroundTasksInASPNET.aspx